# Grails Rendering plugin converting html/gsp from the cloud or from string

Tags: java, grails, pdfrenderer

Currently examples from the Grails rendering plugin documentation shows this:

> pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/pdfs/report", model: [data:
>   data])

The problem is that the html template  I need to render to `pdf` is in a database. Is it possible to use a url (or maybe an html string) as a source of the template?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick; you need to build the `Document` manually and pass it into `render`:

```
XhtmlDocumentService xhtmlDocumentService
def methodName() {
    def document = xhtmlDocumentService.createDocument("<html>")
    pdfRenderingService.render([model: [data: data]], document)
}
```

where "" is the string version of the html markup you want to render.